# Connecting from kotlin to mysql

Tags: mysql, kotlin

I'm getting an error connection my kotlin app to a mysql server. The error is:

```
"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."
```

The credentials are correct and i'm able to connect to the db from the workbench.
What am I missing?

The mysql server is in a Ubuntu cloud instance

The code is here:

```
package com.example.mysql2

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Button(onClick={main()} )
                    {
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    // Database connection parameters
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/myschema"
    val user = "user"
    val password = "pass"

    var connection: Connection? = null

    try {
        // Connect to the database
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)

        // Perform database operations
        // Example: Execute a query
        val statement = connection.createStatement()
        val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lixo")

        // Process the result set
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            val id = resultSet.getInt("id")
            val name = resultSet.getString("name")
            println("ID: $id, Name: $name")
        }
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        // Close the connection
        try {
            connection?.close()
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

The gradle file

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.mysql2"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.mysql2"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.30")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

I tried to change the url to a different one, a wrong one, and the error was the same.

Comment: I noticed in your original code snippet, the connection URL does not specify a database name.

Comment: Just edited the code to add the database name. The error remains the same.